# Check to see if numbers in a column are sequential via command line

Tags: bash, awk, command-line, number-formatting, string-parsing

In a text file, I have a sequence of numbers in a column preceded by a short string.  It is the 5th column in the example file here under "NAME":

```
SESSION NAME:   session
SAMPLE RATE:    48000.000000
BIT DEPTH:  16-bit
SESSION START TIMECODE: 00:00:00:00.00
TIMECODE FORMAT:    24 Frame
# OF AUDIO TRACKS:  2
# OF AUDIO CLIPS:   2
# OF AUDIO FILES:   2


M A R K E R S  L I S T I N G
#       LOCATION        TIME REFERENCE      UNITS       NAME                                COMMENTS
2       0:00.500        24000               Samples     xxxx0001                            
3       0:03.541        170000              Samples     xxxx0002                            
4       0:05.863        281458              Samples     xxxx0003                            
5       0:08.925        428430              Samples     xxxx0004                            
6       0:10.604        509025              Samples     xxxx0005                            
7       0:13.973        670742              Samples     xxxx0006                            
8       0:15.592        748453              Samples     xxxx0008                            
9       0:19.243        923666              Samples     xxxx0008
```

In the example above, 0007 is missing, and 0008 is duplicated.

Therefore, I would like to be able to check if the numbers are:

> 1. sequential given the range that presently exists in the column.
> 2. if there are any duplicates

I would also like to output these results:

```
SKIPPED:
xxxx0007

DUPLICATES:
xxxx0008
```

The furthest I have been able to get is to use `awk` to get the column I need:

`cat <file.txt> | awk '{ print $5 }'`

which gets me to this:

```
NAME
xxxx0001
xxxx0002
xxxx0003
xxxx0004
xxxx0005
xxxx0006
xxxx0008
xxxx0008
```

But I do not know where to go from here.

Do I need to loop through the list items and parse so I get the number only, then start doing some comparisons to the next line?

Any help would be tremendously appreciated
Thank you!

Comment: is there a reason why you try to do this in awk, and not a higher level language (e.g. perl, python, Java etc). I'm not quite sure how is to do this with 1 (one) traversal. Even if it will be possible in `awk` (I'm confident it is), the code will be complicated to maintain.

Comment: @azbarcea I have not tried them in perl, Python or any other language because I am not well versed!  I know this is easier to do higher level, but I am determined to figure out how to do it at the command line!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a starting point, please try the following:

```
awk '
NR>1 { gsub("[^0-9]", "", $5); count[$5]++ }
END {
    print "Skipped:"
    for (i=1; i<NR; i++)
        if (count[i] == 0) printf "xxxx%04d\n", i
    print "Duplicates:"
    for (i=1; i<NR; i++)
        if (count[i] > 1) printf "xxxx%04d\n", i
} ' file.txt
```

Output:

```
Skipped:
xxxx0007
Duplicates:
xxxx0008
```

- The condition `NR>1` is used to skip the top header line.
- `gsub("[^0-9]", "", $5)` removes non-number characters from `$5`.
  As a result, `$5` is set to a number extracted from the 5th column.
- The array `count[]` counts the occurances of each number. If the value
  is `0` (or undefined), it means the number is skipped. If the value
  is larger than `1`, the number is duplicated.
- The `END { ... }` block is executed *after* all the input lines are processed
  and it is useful to report the final results.

However, the "Skipped/Duplicates" approach cannot well detect such cases as:

```
#       LOCATION        TIME REFERENCE      UNITS       NAME            COMMENTS
1       0:00.500        24000               Samples     xxxx0001
2       0:02.888        138652              Samples     xxxx0003
3       0:04.759        228446              Samples     xxxx0004
4       0:07.050        338446              Samples     xxxx0005
5       0:09.034        433672              Samples     xxxx0006
6       0:12.061        578958              Samples     xxxx0007
7       0:14.111        677333              Samples     xxxx0008
8       0:17.253        828181              Samples     xxxx0009
```

or

```
#       LOCATION        TIME REFERENCE      UNITS       NAME            COMMENTS
1       0:00.500        24000               Samples     xxxx0001
2       0:02.888        138652              Samples     xxxx0003
3       0:04.759        228446              Samples     xxxx0002
4       0:07.050        338446              Samples     xxxx0004
5       0:09.034        433672              Samples     xxxx0005
6       0:12.061        578958              Samples     xxxx0006
7       0:14.111        677333              Samples     xxxx0007
8       0:17.253        828181              Samples     xxxx0008
```

It will be better to perform a line-by-line comparison between expected value and the actual value.  Then how about:

```
awk '
NR>1 {
    gsub("[^0-9]", "", $5)
    if ($5 != NR-1) printf "Line: %d  Expected: xxxx%04d  Actual: xxxx%04d\n", NR, NR-1, $5
} ' file.txt
```

output for the original example:

```
Line: 8  Expected: xxxx0007  Actual: xxxx0008
```

**[EDIT]**

According to the revised input file which includes more extra header lines, how about:

```
awk '
f {
    gsub("[^0-9]", "", $5)
    if ($5 != NR-skip) printf "Line: %d  Expected: xxxx%04d  Actual: xxxx%04d\n", NR, NR-skip, $5
}
/^#[[:blank:]]+LOCATION[[:blank:]]+TIME REFERENCE/ {
    skip = NR
    f = 1
}
' file.txt
```

Output:

```
Line: 19  Expected: xxxx0007  Actual: xxxx0008
```

The script above skips the lines until the specific pattern `#       LOCATION        TIME REFERENCE` is found.

- The `f { ... }` block is executed if `f` is true. So the block is skipped
  until `f` is set to a nonzero value.
- The `/^# .../ { ... }` block is executed if the input line matches the
  pattern. If found, `skip` is set to the number of header lines and
  `f` (flag) is set to 1 so the upper block is executed from the next
  iteration.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This also works!!  but how do I treat a case where there are extra lines at the top in my next example below??

Comment: I've updated my answer according to the case. Would you please test it?

Comment: It works for the new text pattern with extra lines! 

However I would still rather see only the numbers that were skipped or duplicated, and not the entire list.  My actual text file cases have more than 200 lines long, so I would rather see a shorter list.

Comment: Now you may have got how to report skipped or duplicate lines (in my initial answer) and how to treat extra header lines (in my last answer). You can write your desirable version by combining these snippets. If you still have a problem, please post 1) your code, 2) a minimal set of input lines to reproduce the problem, 3) expected output. Then we could help you complete the code. Good luck!

Comment: I've added some explanations in my answer. Hope it helps you understand the code.